# No Pre-Release Tags if Major Version is 0

Tags: python, bump2version

I am using `bump2version` with semantic versioning. Is there a way to prevent the pre-release components of a tag from appearing if the major verison is 0 (i.e. rapid development?). As it stands, my `.bumpversion.cfg` is

```
[bumpversion]
current_version = 0.0.0
tag = False
tag_name = {new_version}
commit = True
parse =
    (?P<major>\d+)
    \.
    (?P<minor>\d+)
    \.
    (?P<patch>\d+)
    (\-(?P<pre>[a-z]+)\.(?P<prenum>\d+))?
serialize =
    {major}.{minor}.{patch}-{pre}.{prenum}
    {major}.{minor}.{patch}

[bumpversion:part:pre]
optional_value = placeholder
first_value = alpha
values =
    alpha
    beta
    rc
    placeholder

[bumpversion:part:prenum]
first_value = 1

[bumpversion:file:pyproject.toml]
```

which adds pre-release values when I bump part `minor`

```
>>> bumpversion minor
Bumpversion: 0.0.0 -> 0.1.0-alpha.1
```

I don't want the `-alpha.N`, `-beta.N`, etc., part of the tag to appear when I'm at major version `0` (i.e. rapid development; pre-release testing doesn't occur for me until major version `1` and higher).

I do want the pre-relase parts when going from major rev `0` to `1` or `N` to `N+1` for all `N > 0` (because pre-release testing will occur at these stages), just not for rapid development. I'd hate to have to manually type out `--new-version` for every bump while I'm in rapid development (esp. because I'll have a lot of versions until 1.0.0).

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not doing `bumpversion minor --no-tag` ?

Comment: @florisla Because I do want a tag. I just don't want the pre-release parts of the tag to appear when I'm at major version `0` (rapid development). I'll update the wording of my question because I can see how that would be misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a "monkey-patch"/workaround, in `bumpversion.version_part`, I edited the function `_choose_serialize_format()` from

```
def _choose_serialize_format(self, version, context):

        chosen = None

        logger.debug(
            "Available serialization formats: '%s'", "', '".join(self.serialize_formats)
        )

        for serialize_format in self.serialize_formats:
            try:
                self._serialize(
                    version, serialize_format, context, raise_if_incomplete=True
                )
                chosen = serialize_format
                logger.debug("Found '%s' to be a usable serialization format", chosen)
            except IncompleteVersionRepresentationException as e:
                if not chosen:
                    chosen = serialize_format
            except MissingValueForSerializationException as e:
                logger.info(e.message)
                raise e

        if not chosen:
            raise KeyError("Did not find suitable serialization format")

        logger.debug("Selected serialization format '%s'", chosen)

        return chosen
```

to

```
def _choose_serialize_format(self, version, context):

        chosen = None

        logger.debug(
            "Available serialization formats: '%s'", "', '".join(self.serialize_formats)
        )

        if version._values["major"].value == "0":
            _serialize_formats = [
                self.serialize_formats[-1],
            ]
        else:
            _serialize_formats = self.serialize_formats

        for serialize_format in _serialize_formats:
            try:
                self._serialize(
                    version, serialize_format, context, raise_if_incomplete=True
                )
                chosen = serialize_format
                logger.debug("Found '%s' to be a usable serialization format", chosen)
            except IncompleteVersionRepresentationException as e:
                if not chosen:
                    chosen = serialize_format
            except MissingValueForSerializationException as e:
                logger.info(e.message)
                raise e

        if not chosen:
            raise KeyError("Did not find suitable serialization format")

        logger.debug("Selected serialization format '%s'", chosen)

        return chosen
```

The lines added are

```
if version._values["major"].value == "0":
    _serialize_formats = [
        self.serialize_formats[-1],
    ]
else:
    _serialize_formats = self.serialize_formats
```

and the lines changed are

```
for serialize_format in self.serialize_formats:
```

to

```
for serialize_format in _serialize_formats:
```